# My dropdown menu items push each other around

Tags: css

I am attempting to make a drop-down menu. My problem is that some of the drop-down items are wider than their parent item. This is causing my other menu items to be displaced. In this case, hovering above "Practice Areas" will displace "About".

Hopefully a css guru can help me with this.

Thanks, CPR

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
}

.main-nav>ul>li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.sub-menu li {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.main-nav ul li:hover > ul.sub-menu li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class='main-nav'>
  <ul>
    <li>Practice Areas
      <ul class='sub-menu'>
        <li>Consumer Bankruptcy</li>
        <li>Personal Injury</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>About
      <ul class='sub-menu'>
        <li>Meet us</li>
        <li>Testimonials</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Contact HR.  If menu items are pushing each other around, that's a hostile coding environment and shouldn't be tolerated.

Answer (score 2):

I've added

```
.sub-menu {
      position: absolute;      
    }
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
}

.main-nav>ul>li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
.sub-menu {
  position: absolute;      
}
.sub-menu li {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.main-nav ul li:hover > ul.sub-menu li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class='main-nav'>
  <ul>
    <li>Practice Areas
      <ul class='sub-menu'>
        <li>Consumer Bankruptcy</li>
        <li>Personal Injury</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>About
      <ul class='sub-menu'>
        <li>Meet us</li>
        <li>Testimonials</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to absolutely position the sub menu....

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
}

.main-nav > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

ul > li > ul  {
  position: absolute;}

.sub-menu li {
  display: none;
}

.main-nav ul li:hover > ul.sub-menu li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class='main-nav'>
  <ul>
    <li>Practice Areas
      <ul class='sub-menu'>
        <li>Consumer Bankruptcy</li>
        <li>Personal Injury</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>About
      <ul class='sub-menu'>
        <li>Meet us</li>
        <li>Testimonials</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the width of each `li` item. I used `30%` in the css for `.main-nav>ul>li`.

```
.main-nav>ul>li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;             <===== added this
}
```

Of course, this won't work well if you need more than 3 `li` items in your navigation bar. I would suggest using `bootstrap`. Here is the [bootstrap navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
}

.main-nav>ul>li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
}

.sub-menu li {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.main-nav ul li:hover > ul.sub-menu li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class='main-nav'>
  <ul>
    <li>Practice Areas
      <ul class='sub-menu'>
        <li>Consumer Bankruptcy</li>
        <li>Personal Injury</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>About
      <ul class='sub-menu'>
        <li>Meet us</li>
        <li>Testimonials</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```